# Identify changes in the slope using machine learning

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, classification

I want to get my hands dirty with some machine learning, and I finally have a problem which seems like a good beginner project. However, despite reading a lot about the subject I am unsure how to get started, and what my basic approach should be.

[I have a dataset which should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OP6G8.jpg).

[image]

a real dataset looks more like this:

[image]

I want to identify the points in the red circles (on the first image), and be robust against occasional artifacts like the one in the blue circle.

I sounds like a really easy task. However, the is quite a lot of noise in the raw data. My current implementation is pretty traditional. It blurs the data and compares the first and second derivative to some estimated threshold values. This approach works, but can "only" identify the points with ~99.7% accuracy, but since I do around 100.000 measurements a day I would love to increase this number.

So, this is what I have:

1. All the datasets I want/need
2. A pretty good model of how the data should look.
3. A pretty good training set, using my existing algorithm (the outlines can be fixed manually)

However, **I do not have a basic idea how what approach I should use.** I feels like none of the material I've read on machine learning fit's this problem.

Can someone help me with the super high level approach to solve this problem?

Comment: This sounds more like some sort of smoothing or local regression (LOESS ?) than a traditional machine learning algorithm.

Comment: maybe a Kalman filter?

Comment: It looks like a red circle is defined by a minimum persistent slope change over a certain distance.  The blue point fails because the change in slope is not persistent, i.e. it is just noise.

Comment: @GordonLinoff never heard of LOESS before. I'm currently reading about it.

Comment: @wildplasser also never heard about that before

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen True. But my experience tells me that those kind of approaches all fail in rare case

Comment: How are you determining the control?  In other words, how is a red circle being determined as a red circle outside the algorithm?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen 'm sorry. I do not quite understand your question. Are you asking what the red circle represents physically? or how I determine their position manually?

Comment: I was asking about the latter.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Well, I just look for changes in the slope. I know there is suppose to be 3 on each side of the blob. The first and last points are pretty obvious, the center point is more tricky. What I really do is identifying the approximate location, and then fit a second degree polynomial on each side of the approximate location in order to find the intersection point.

Comment: My point: Would the naked eye necessarily do any worse than a good detection algorithm?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Do any worse? It is not hard to find the locations with the naked eye, and if I could just come close to my brains performance I would be very happy. The cases where I actually have doubt about the locations are very rare.

Comment: Would you like to detect the points in an unsupervised way, or do you have training examples with the red points marked? That could make a difference in the type of algorithm to be used.

Comment: i'd do what you're doing, but instead of comparing to some threshold values, train an SVM with a linear kernel (i don't think anything more would be necessary) on sliding windows of your computed values. That'll learn the best cutoff values. On a more meta note, there is no right or wrong answer to this question, and no way for any of us to be sure we've found an answer. (And it'd still be suspect even if you gave us a pile of training data.)